# Multiple Condition for a same column in Where clause

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I need all the task which are not 'Closed' and also the closed task between the selected date range. There are few old task where closeddate is null so I tried as below sample query. 
But the result does not include the closed task between the date range.

```
select * 
from task 
where id = 5 
and ((closedDate is null and staus <>'Closed') 
    or (closedDate between '7/10/2021 8:00:00 AM' AND '7/16/2021 8:00:00 AM'))`
```

Comment: The date range should be in YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss format.

Comment: A column named `Id` is usually *unique* - assuming that's not the case with your data

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: When i was checking with only condition (closedDate between '7/10/2021 8:00:00 AM' AND '7/16/2021 8:00:00 AM') the result displays correctly. There is no problem with the format.

Comment: Yeah Id I mention above is not the unique one but we have task_id as primary key for the table.